# Yet another issue with 'Could not resolve state to state'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `ui-router` and my states are:

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  templateUrl: "assets/views/app.html",
  abstract: true
}).state('app.dashboard', {
  url: "/dashboard",
  templateUrl: "assets/views/pages_timeline.html",
  title: 'Dashboard',
  controller: 'TimelineCtrl'
}).state('app.user.services', {
  url: "/user/services",
  templateUrl: "assets/views/user_services.html",
  title: 'Service Integrations'
})
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-right-big smooth"></div>',
  abstract: true
}).state('login.signin', {
  url: '/signin',
  templateUrl: "assets/views/login_login.html",
  controller: 'AuthenticationCtrl'
}).state('login.forgot', {
  url: '/forgot',
  templateUrl: "assets/views/login_forgot.html"
}).state('login.registration', {
  url: '/registration',
  templateUrl: "assets/views/login_registration.html"
})
```

I am currently in the `app.dashboard` state, and I have a link:

```
            <a ui-sref="app.user.services">
                Service Integrations
            </a>
```

However, when I click it, I get an error: `Error: Could not resolve 'app.user.services' from state 'app'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: know nothing about this, but idea that u need to define state app.user or use app.userservices (without dot inside) seems legit xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot `.` notation is used to specify a parent relationship in `ui-router`, so the parent of state `dashboard` is state `app`.

With `app.user.services` there is no parent state `app.user`. So you need to define it (you can make it abstract):

```
.state("app.user", {
   abstract: true,
   template: "<div ui-view></div>"
})
```